# How to create a dropdown variable with tag values in a Grafana dashboard?

Tags: grafana, influxdb, k6, grafana-templating

I am using Grafana and InfluxDB with K6. My tests are generating data for some metrics and I am always defining a test-wide tag `testrunname` which is set to a different value every time.

In Grafana, I want to add a variable in my dashboard, and I want it to be one of all the available values so far added for the tests that I run. Basically the dropdown will have to display all the values of tag `testrunname` available in the database.

[image]

Not having much luck so far.
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The query is:

```
SHOW TAG VALUES WITH KEY = "testrunname"
```

From [documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/explore-schema/#examples-5).